# GNOME temporarily freezes when changing virtual desktop

Tags: gnome, freeze

Usually when I'm changing the virtual desktop, GNOME temporarily (until I move the mouse either at all or to the other screen or I press the Super/Windows key) freezes.  I can still do everything, just the output is not changing.

I tried to search on the internet if the problem is already known, but I couldn't find anything.

I use Debian testing and GNOME 44.5.

PS: Due to a bug in SE I can't add comments or expand the comment list after the first five (or however many are normally shown), which is why I usually add comments here as Edits.